# How to send Binary Data as it is with json response without encoding?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I required to send binary data as it is in json response without converting it into encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is impossible to fulfill.

The JSON syntax does not provide any way to represent binary data without first encoding it as text characters.

The only "get out" would be if the so-called binary data is actually text data and consists of characters that are all legal in JSON strings without any escaping.  (Informally, any Unicode code-point apart from `"`, `\` or control characters.  See [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) for a more formal specification.)